# Changing Column Settings for a Content Type using Powershell

Tags: powershell, content-type

I'm trying to change the setting of a column to make it not a required field. This is the code I'm using:

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("abc.com")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()

$MyContentType=$web.ContentTypes["ContentType"]
$MyField=$MyContentType.Fields | Where {$_.Id -eq $web.Fields["Column"].id}
$MyContentType.FieldLinks[$MyField.Id].Required=$False 

$MyContentType.Update()
```

But this is giving error that `$MyContentType.FieldLinks` is `NULL`. How can I successfully execute my PowerShell script?

Comment: Two notes here, a bit off topic: 1. There is no need to open an SPSIte object first - go straight for the SPWeb: $web = Get-SPWeb "http://example.com" 2. Dispose of opened SPSite and SPWeb objects by calling .Dispose();

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```
$web = get-spweb $url
$MyContentType = $web.ContentTypes["ContentType"]
$field = $MyContentType.FieldLinks["Column"]
$field.Required = $False 
$MyContentType.Update()
```

Comment: $field = $MyContentType.FieldLinks["Column"]
This throws cannot index into null array..and the next two lines too

Comment: What is the url u are passing?

Comment: http://abc.abc.abc.com/sites/abc12 - The URL is of this pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("abc.com")
$web = $site.rootweb

$MyContentType=$web.ContentTypes["ContentType"]

$Fields=$MyContentType.Fieldlinks
$Field=$Fields["Internal Name of the Field"] #Type $MyContentType.Fieldlinks to get the details of all the fields.
$Field.Required=$false
$MyContentType.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks.But I don't want to modify it at root level.

Comment: ok. please check this link. http://paulryan.com.au/2013/ct-field-props/ this may be helpful to you